# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in udp client server program to transfer a file

Tags: c

I have written code for UDP client server to transfer a file in "C". Both client and server are compiled without any errors. But on executing client it is showing an runtime error "segmentation fault(core dumped)" . Any solution??

**my code:**

**server.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#define SERV_PORT 6349
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{    
char filename[80],recvline[80];
FILE *fp;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
int clilen,sockfd;
sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port=htons(SERV_PORT);
bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);
recvfrom(sockfd,filename,80,0,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&clilen);
printf("\n date in the file is \n ");
fp=fopen(filename,"r");
while(fgets(recvline,80,fp)!=NULL)
{
printf("\n %s\n ",recvline);
}
fclose(fp);   
}
```

/**client.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define SERV_PORT 6349
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
char filename[80];
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port=htons(SERV_PORT);
inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&servaddr.sin_addr);
printf("enter the file name");
scanf("%s",filename);
sendto(sockfd,filename,strlen(filename),0,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
}
```

Comment: Before asking it is expected that  you at do at least some basic debugging on your own. Use a debugger and/or debug print statements. And do basic error checking for each function call.

Comment: are you sure you're passing an argument to the client code (ie, does `argv[1]` exist?)

Comment: among other errors, you're sending `strlen(filename)` characters which does not include the terminating 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the gdb debugger, it'll tell you the line that you have the seg fault on.

Tutorial at: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/

Running your code did not give a segfault to me though, so I'm guessing you didn't include an argument at the command line for argv[1]